# How to integrate vuejs in a django project?

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

we need to create a complete website with django and vue as part of a school project, however, we are having trouble integrating vue into our django project.

To keep things simple we want to use vue directly in an index.html file located in a django application in templates/app/index.html thanks to the vue cdn.

Without vue, the page content is displayed by django, but when we try to use vue with the cdn in this file, nothing is displayed and we get this error in the chrome console:

> vue.global.js:1661 [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render
> function.

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

    <div id="app">{{ message }}</div>

    <script>
        const { createApp } = Vue

        createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    message: 'Hello Vue!'
                }
            }
        }).mount('#app')
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

when we run the html file directly in chrome (outside of django) everything works, which means the problem comes from djangom. We suspect the problem is that django expects to run django templating code and not vuejs code.

Is it possible to use vue js in this way on django and if not, how to integrate vue with django?

Comment: Django is totally unaware of Vue. You can check the response from django. It's quite possible that it interpolates `{{ message }}` on server side while it shouldn't

Comment: Django is unaware of Vue but use the same template language syntax. Could be that the `{{ message }}` is picked up by django but missed by Vue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vue.js and Django template language use the same delimiters (`{{` and `}}`) by default. You need to change one of them to a different one, e.g. for [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-compileroptions):

```
<div id="app">[[ message ]]</div>

<script>
    const { createApp } = Vue

    createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                message: 'Hello Vue!'
            }
        },

        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    }).mount('#app')
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, isn't it better to use {{ }} as a delimiter? And so you we have to use this statement for each vue component?

Comment: You need to set this delimiter only at the Vue.js app and its child components will use this setting. You can use Vue.js with the original delimiters if you go the Single Page App way, so Vue.js will handle 100% of the frontend and Django will be used only through a JSON API source. This way Django wont render the template, so no more delimiter issue. If Vue.js is not a strict requirement I would recommend [Alpine.js](https://alpinejs.dev/) that has similar syntax like Vue.js but it works well with Django out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Using `{% verbatim %} Contents here {% endverbatim %}` is a better approach when integrating Vue.js with Django templates if you want to avoid conflicts between Vue.js and Django template delimiters. This method tells Django to treat the content inside as raw text without processing Django template tags.

Here's how you can use `{% verbatim %}` with Vue.js:

1. In your Django template, wrap the section of your HTML that you want to be processed by Vue.js inside `{% verbatim %}` tags. For example:

```html
{% verbatim %}
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
{% endverbatim %}
```

This will prevent Django from interpreting the content inside `{% verbatim %}` and `{% endverbatim %}` as Django template tags.

2. In your Vue.js script, you don't need to change the delimiters. You can leave them at their default values:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      message: "This is a message using Vue default delimiters",
    };
});

app.mount("#app");
```

With this approach, the content inside `{% verbatim %}` will be processed by Vue.js as expected, and the rest of the Django template will remain unaffected.

Using `{% verbatim %}` is a good way to keep your Vue.js and Django template code separate and avoid any unintentional conflicts between their delimiters. It allows you to integrate Vue.js seamlessly into your Django project.